# Nested Control With Datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

This ListView in aspx code below is nested in another ListView. The code behind below is for the ListView which wrap the nested. I want on every iteration time the wrapper ListView to pass property "Comments" in the datasource of the nested ListView. I tried to do this with the code-behind with event "ItemDataBound"(this event is for the wrapper ListView) but, when I run the code I am gertting this exception:  **DataBinding: 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[[BlogProfile.Data.Comment, BlogProfile.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' does not contain a property with the name 'Author'.**  All I want is every time the wrapper ListView to pass different datasource to the nested ListView and this nested ListView to take this datasource with "Eval(...)" like I wrote in aspx code. What I miss here. I think that the problem might be that I am not using the right event here ?

aspx code:

```
       <asp:ListView ID="CommentListView" runat="server" >
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <div class="postComments">
                     <span class="authorComment"><%# Eval("Author") %></span>
                       :
                      <span class="commentContent"><%# Eval("Message") %></span>
                 </div>
              </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:ListView>
```

code behind:

```
   protected void PostsListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        BlogProfileEntities blogProfile = new BlogProfileEntities();
        var listview = e.Item.FindControl("CommentListView") as ListView;
        var hiddenfield = e.Item.FindControl("CurrentPostIDHiddenField") as HiddenField;
        int id = int.Parse(hiddenfield.Value);
        listview.DataSource = (from p in blogProfile.Posts
                               where p.PostID == id
                               select p.Comments).ToList();
        listview.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is based on your entity framework. It occured at the time of adding the ADO.NET entity FW component into your system. Please readd the component again. Also check with you table column name added in your entity FW